# toggle + toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am using toggle function in Jquery. There is a button which reveals content (this part work fine) I would like to add class when button is active.I think toggle class is what I need. So far I have

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(".left-menu-button").click(function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    $(".left-menu-content").toggle("slow", function() {
      $that.toggleClass(".left-menu-button-active");
    });
  });


< /script>
```

```css
.left-menu {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
}
.left-menu-button {
  background: #00447f;
  width: 76px;
  height: 140px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #00447f;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.left-menu-content {
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 186px;
  width: 295px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  position: relative!important;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
.left-menu-content section {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.left-menu-button-active {
  background: #000;
  color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
  background: #00447f;
  width: 76px;
  height: 140px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #00447f;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<section class="left-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="left-menu-content">    
                  <section class=" updates-area left-menu-content">
               <h2><a href="#">Latest News</a></h2>
       <span class="read-more text-center">
                   <a href="#">Read more</a>
                 </span>

</section>{% endblock %}
</span>
<a class="left-menu-button icon-document93">News</a>

</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

There is a content beneath that blue button. I cannot add class and toggle at the same time. Please help. .left-menu-button should change it's class on toggle and reveal content.

Comment: it seems that it is not working at all as soon as I tried to add toggleClass

Comment: Fix your snippet first so that we can understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the dot in the selector like below.

```
$that.toggleClass("left-menu-button-active");
```

and change the the inner `left-menu-content` class as `$(".left-menu-content").toggle` is firing twice.

```
$(".left-menu-button").click(function() {
    var $that = $(this);
    $(".left-menu-content").toggle("slow", function() {
        $that.toggleClass("left-menu-button-active");
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/32t3y423/1/)

**UPDATE**

Your new criteria can work like so:-

```
$(".left-menu-button").click(function() {
     var $that = $(this);
     $(this).parent().find(".left-menu-content").toggle("slow", function() {
        $that.toggleClass("left-menu-button-active");
    });
});
```

Comment: It works nicely but now that I added another item it reveals all toggled content.How to make it toggle just relevant content to that button?

Comment: Update your question with the relevant html.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated snippet. Target is to get this "drawers" work independently. If i click latest news - only that block should reveal itself.

```js
$(".left-menu-button").click(function() {
  var $that = $(this);
  $(".left-menu-content").toggle("slow", function() {
    $that.toggleClass("left-menu-button-active");
  });
});
```

```css
/* LEFT MENU */

.left-menu {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
}
.left-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.left-menu-button {
  background: #00447f;
  width: 76px;
  height: 140px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left-menu-content {
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 186px;
  width: 295px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
  position: relative!important;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
.left-menu-content section {
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.left-menu-button-active {
  background: #000;
  color: red;
  background: #ffba4c;
  color: #00447f;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -7px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -7px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -7px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.left-menu-button:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="left-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span class="left-menu-content">    
      <section>
 
          
        </section>
  </span>
      <a class="left-menu-button icon-document93">Latest News</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span class="left-menu-content">    
        <section>

        </section>
  </span>
      <a class="left-menu-button icon-calendar-icons">Calendar Dates</a>
    </li>







    <li>
      <span class="left-menu-content">    
   <section class="maps-address">
</section>
  </span>
      <a class="left-menu-button icon-map32">Location and address</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <span class="left-menu-content">    
     <section class="social">
          <a href ="">Twitter</a>
          <a href ="">facebook</a>  
          <a href ="">Youtube</a>  
            
        </section>
  </span>
      <a class="left-menu-button icon-document93">Social</a>
    </li>


  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this job,I have just edited `jquery`

```
$(".left-menu-button").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().children('.left-menu-content').toggle("slow", function() {
  });
});
```